# Get windows.storage.fileproperties namespace in visual studio pro 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, add-references-dialog

I'd like to use methods in the `videoproperties` class in `windows.storage.fileproperties` but I cant find it when i try to **add reference** to my project.

Where can I download the namespace and how do I add it to visual studio?

Comment: You can download from google ->go to solution explorer ->right click->Add Existing Item->add it in your project

Comment: I'd like to download it directly from Microsoft but cant see where to get it.